# Is ὅλος not more apt than πάντα

Tags: greek

The word πάντα gives a sense of eternity i.e. time quantity as opposed to ὅλος. Would Matthew 28:19 not have been more aptly written as ὅλος έθνη instead of πάντα τὰ έθνη as ὅλος is used in the original text so known at the time.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 3):

πάντα has no inherent sense of time. It simply means “all, every”. If I were to say in English, “Are you going to eat **all** that?” or in Koine Greek, «Μὴ μέλλεις φαγεῖν **πάντα** ἐκεῖνα?», neither indicates any sense whatsoever of time, especially eternity.

Comment: Why do Greek dictionaries list πάντα as always and όλα as all?

Comment: @Waslap—Please cite your source and the entry so we can further discuss.

Comment: I consulted Wiktionary and a Greek dictionary on my phone. Even Google translate confirms. I updated the question to rather use the root of όλα

Comment: The New Testament is Koine Greek, closer to Classical Greek than Modern Greek.  Modern Greek definitions don't always match the New Testament.